# Responding JSON according to JSON API in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I created an rails api to expose my Bottl class. This class has some methods for solving the [99Bottles](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/99_Bottles_of_Beer) problem. The `song` method, for instance, returns the complete lyrics song. My intention is to return a JSON, according to [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) containing the response of that method.

```
require_relative '../bottles_logic/bottles'

class SongsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_song, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /songs
  def index
    @songs = ::Bottl.new.song

    render json: @songs
  end
end
```

Using Postman, I get 200 status and the request payload, however, JSON is not shown due to `syntax error (unexpected 'S')`.

My questions are:

- How to return a JSON according to the JSON API in this case?
- Do I need to use a Serializer to format this JSON?
- I'd like to return the lyrics in a json entry called whole_song, so it must be an attribute, right?

Comment: Hey, can you share the rest of the error log? you should find it in your server logs. thanks!

Comment: 'Started GET "/songs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-04 09:22:52 -0300
Processing by SongsController#index as */*
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)'

Comment: Thanks for sharing this part of the log! Do you have a view of the rest of the log? to be precise, the line `syntax error (unexpected 'S')` and the lines right after?

Comment: That error is showing up only in Postman "pretty" section. In "Raw" section, I can see the full payload, but it does not render as json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What data class are you store in @songs?
You must pass the hash to render method, for example, `render json: { key: value }`.
If @songs is an object of your class, you must try to use Serializer or `@songs.as_json`.

Comment: '@songs 'is a String. So is I want it rendered in "whole_song" key, so I have to run render json: { whole_song: '@songs '}, right? Using Serialilzer or' @songs.as_json', I want to have it showed as whole_song attribute. How can I create an atributte?

Comment: > So is I want it rendered in "whole_song" key, so I have to run render json: { whole_song: '@songs '}, right?
Yes. You do not need to create attribute if `@songs` is a String.
`render json: { whole_song: @songs }`

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! But is it according to JSON API? I think I have to add other fields to the JSON response

Comment: The simplest way for you will be adding keys to hash.
`render json: { whole_song: @songs, album: @album, artist: @artist }`
Also, you can use local variables instead of instance variables.